# Mongodb timezone issue when filtering by date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

I am trying to get all records with "date" field between startDate and endDate.

I am querying the DB with this (to get records from beginning of the month until today):

```
 var startDate = new Date(2017,09,1); 
    var endDate = new Date(2017,09,7); 

//console.log(startDate) = Sun Oct 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
//console.log(endDate) = Sat Oct 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)

    Sale.find({date:{"$gte":startDate,"$lt":endDate}},function(err, sales){

    }
```

Records with dates between 10/02 and 10/07 and being returned, but records with date 10/01 are not being returned. Here is the date field of those missing records:

```
 "date": {
        "$date": "2017-10-01T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
```

I set the hour to 23 to see if it would make a difference (timezone,etc) but it didn't.

If I set the startDate to September 30 hour 23, nothing. Hour 22, 21, nothing. **When startDate becomes September 30, hour 20, bingo, the records are returned.**

This is probably a timezone issue, but I can't identify where and how.

Comment: In JS, `new Date(2017,09,1);` returns `Wed Nov 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` because 0 is January. That doesn't explain the behavior you're seeing, however.

Comment: What timezone is your data being written to MongoDB in? UTC or local?

Comment: Local, but so should be the new Date() object right? I updated the question with the console.log of the dates.

Comment: `Sun Oct 01 2017 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)` would be `Sun Oct 02 2017 02:00:00 GMT-0000`, so move it from 2300 to like 1600 and see what happens.

Comment: But  Oct 02 is greater than startDate, so it should be returned!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156180/discussion-between-jason-fry-and-daniel-scocco).

Comment: What is the actual value you are comparing with? If you're -0300, then `new Date(2017,09,1)` is 2017-10-01T03:00:00Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `2017-10-01T23:00:00.000Z` is GMT time.
This `new Date(2017,10,01);` is your local time and does not equal to the above as soon as you are not sitting on Greenwich meridian.

JS stores dates in GMT seconds since some base date.

So in first case number of seconds is `X` and in second case it is `X + Date.getTimezoneOffset()`.

You can use this function:

```
function ZDate(year,month,day) {
  return new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
}
```

Or as RobG suggested:

```
function ZDate(year,month,day) {
  return Date.UTC(year, month-1, day); 
}
```

here:

```
var startDate = ZDate(2017,09,1); 
var endDate = ZDate(2017,09,7); `
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. But you need to decide first what does it mean 2017,09,1 for you. Date in your local TZ then your code is correct or 2017,09,1 is GMT then use ZDate above.

Comment: Note that in ISO 8601, Date-only forms do not allow a timezone so an appended "Z" is either ignored or treated as in an invalid date. Since ECMA-262 ed 6, date-only forms *should* be treated as UTC (contrary to ISO 8601), so `new Date('2017-10-01')` is UTC. If you want to explicitly treat it as UTC, then `new Date(Date.UTC(y, m-1, d))` is a much better way to go (and avoids the vagaries of the built-in parser).